# How to Implement SSJS ContinueRequest?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

How do I implement ContinueRequest on a script like below to bypass the 2500 limit?

```
        <script runat=server>
Platform.Load('Core','1');
var deCustKey = 'KEY'; //your DE's CustomerKey / External Key
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy(); //creates proxy


var moreData = true; //To validate if more data in Retrieve
var reqID = null; //Used with Batch Retrieve to more to next batch

while(moreData) {

    deArr = [];
    var moreData = false;

    var deReturn = retrieveDERows(mid,deCustKey,reqID);
    var moreData = deReturn.HasMoreRows;
    var reqID = deReturn.RequestID;
   
 Write(deReturn.length);
  
}

function retrieveDERows(mid,deCustKey,reqID) {
    var cols = ["abi_email"]; //Columns you want retrieved

    if (reqID == null) {
        var desc = prox.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + deCustKey + "]", cols); //executes the proxy call
    } else {
        desc = prox.getNextBatch("DataExtensionObject[" + deCustKey + "]", reqID);
    }

    return desc;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

ContinueRequest in SSJS is actually in relation to the SOAP API and not to SSJS itself. You won't be able to use it for Core Functions.

So you would have to utilize raw SOAP or the much better choice, WSProxy.

You would build your normal WSProxy request like so:

```js
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load('Core','1.1.1');
var deCustKey = 'DEkey'; //your DE's CustomerKey / External Key
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy(); //creates proxy
var cols = ["SubscriberKey"]; //Columns you want retrieved

var desc = prox.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + deCustKey + "]", cols);
</script>
```

This will return a max of 2500 records.  Now lets look to implement a continue request:

```js
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load('Core','1.1.1');
var deCustKey = 'DEkey'; //your DE's CustomerKey / External Key
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy(); //creates proxy


var moreData = true; //To validate if more data in Retrieve
var reqID = null; //Used with Batch Retrieve to more to next batch

while(moreData) {

    deArr = [];
    var moreData = false;

    var deReturn = retrieveDERows(mid,deCustKey,reqID);
    var moreData = deReturn.HasMoreRows;
    var reqID = deReturn.RequestID;

...insert what you want to do with the returned data here...

}

function retrieveDERows(mid,deCustKey,reqID) {
    var cols = ["SubscriberKey"]; //Columns you want retrieved

    if (reqID == null) {
        var desc = prox.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + deCustKey + "]", cols); //executes the proxy call
    } else {
        desc = prox.getNextBatch("DataExtensionObject[" + deCustKey + "]", reqID);
    }

    return desc;
}
</script>
```

This turns the retrieve into a function and then uses a while() loop to keep looping through the retrieve while using `.getNextBatch` (utilizes continueRequest) to retrieve the next batch automatically instead of having to rebuild and rewrite your API call.

Can find more in-depth information [here](https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-retrieve-more-than-2500-records-from-a-data-extension-with-server-side-javascript/) from an article by Ivan Razine.

Comment: Using the above script, and adding in Write(deReturn.length);

I am getting the below response:
"33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333" instead of the count of rows.

Comment: can you edit your question to include your current state code and I can take a look

Comment: I have updated the script

Comment: @DyllanAndrews So your issue is that you are pulling the top level object which has 3 properties in it.  `HasMoreRows | RequestID | Results` so this means that returning deReturn.length will return 3 for every single run. In order to get the number or rows returned for each loop, you will need to do `Write(deReturn.Results.length);`